# How to test UseEffect with setIntervale in React?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

This is the [Original Issue](https://github.com/MenaiAla/react-push-notify/issues/1).

I have a Notification component where `autohide` is prop that controls the visibility of Notification :

```
    <Notification {...notification} darkmode autohide >
        <Media src={MEDIA_PATH} link='https://www.github.com' />
    </Notification>
```

In my `Notification` Component :

```
const Notification = ({ type, data, style, action, darkmode, autohide, children }) => {
    
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (autohide) {
            setInterval(() => setVisible(false), 5000);
        }
        return () => {
            clearInterval();
        }
    }, [autohide]);

 return (visible && <Wrapper {...props}> { children }</Wrapper>);

}
```

I'm using Enzyme and I want to test `useEffect` :

```
it("should hide the Notification after 5 seconds", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Notification {...props} autohide />)
        // How to say that the component will be hidden after 5 seconds based on its internal state?
    });
```

I tried :

```
    it('should hide the Notification after 5 seconds', () => {
        expect(wrapper.isEmptyRender()).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

But it does not make an impact.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a wait period of time for the test -

1. Set up the component with the props
2. Verify it's rendered
3. Wait 5 seconds within the test
4. Call `wrapper.update()`
5. Verify the render a second time has reached the time and stopped rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Jest has some [fake timers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks). It's a bad idea to wait for 5 secs in your unit tests, as they're meant to be snappy.

Something like this should work:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers();

it("should hide the Notification after 5 seconds", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Notification {...props} autohide />);
        
    jest.runAllTimers();

    expect(wrapper.isEmptyRender()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

This might not work right away (I'm not sure how asynchronicity is handled), but the referenced page should give you some ideas.

Comment: I'm getting this error : `Ran 100000 timers, and there are still more! Assuming we've hit an infinite recursion and bailing out...`

Comment: I guess this will work only if I don't have `useEffect`.

Comment: are you sure you didn't mistake setinterval for setTimeout?

Comment: But it stills fail in `toBeTruthy()` : `recieved:false`

Comment: `   expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 5000);` thi works well but this `expect(wrapper.isEmptyRender()).toBe(true);` does not pass !

Comment: did you try rendering a snapshot?

Comment: This error; `Ran 100000 timers, and there are still more! Assuming we've hit an infinite recursion and bailing out...` is caused by `jest.runAllTimers()`. It should never be used with setInterval. Try `jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()` instead.